# Why was Thus Spake Zarathustra translated into Early Modern English?

Tags: translation, friedrich-nietzsche, thus-spake-zarathustra

I am currently reading *The Power* by Naomi Alderman, and I find that the author writes some sentences in Early Modern English such as

> She maketh a channel for the thunderbolt and setteth a path for the storm.

And this reminds me that the *Thus Spake Zarathustra* was translated into Early Modern English English by [Thomas Common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Common) in 1909. Does anyone know the reasons why it was translated into Early Modern English?

Comment: As far as Common goes, Wikipedia explains "Common reasoned that because the original German was written in a pseudo-Luther-Biblical style, a pseudo-King-James-Biblical style would be fitting in the English translation." But this is interpretation of literature rather than the nuts and bolts of the language.

Comment: For those who are curious, see [Thomas Common's translation on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/thusspokezarathu00nietuoft/). I'll stick with the German original.

Comment: Just FYI, what's usually called [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) is very different from what you're talking about. Sentences like "She maketh a channel for the thunderbolt and setteth a path for the storm", which could be found in 17th to 19th century literature, already count as [Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_English), I think.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers very much! I am doing a presentation on The Power tomorrow at school, as part of the freshmen year English course. I'll look into these links. Thanks again!

Comment: And sorry for making a mistake about the classification of English in different times.

Comment: Don't worry about the term "Early Modern English". The more important issue after your most recent edit is that you turned your post into two questions: one about the Nietzsche translation and one about Naomi Alderman. It is better to post the Naomi Alderman question separately.

Comment: That's right! Thank you for reminding me. Because I am rather new to stacksexchange.com.